# Extract two substrings from a single string in R

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a text field like this :
-- :location: - '12.839006423950195' - '77.6580810546875' :last_location_update: 2015-08-10 16:41:46.817000000 Z

I want to extract 12.839006423950195 and 77.6580810546875 and put them into separate columns in the same data frame.

The length of these numbers vary - the only way to do it is by extracting what is nestled inside the first and second single quotation marks and third and fourth single quotation marks.

I tried using str_locate_all, str_match_all but I can't figure it our. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any library it can be done like that:

```
txt <- ":location: - '12.839006423950195' - '77.6580810546875' :last_location_update: 2015-08-10 16:41:46.817000000 Z"
start<-gregexpr("('.*?)[0-9.](.*?')+",txt)[[1]]+1
end<-start+attr(start,"match.length")-3
df<-data.frame(t(apply(cbind(start[1:2],end[1:2]),1,function(x) substr(txt,x[1],x[2]))))

> df
              X1               X2
1 12.839006423950195 77.6580810546875
```

Thanks to @thelatemail:

```
txt <- ":location: - '12.839006423950195' - '77.6580810546875' :last_location_update: 2015-08-10 16:41:46.817000000 Z"
df<-data.frame(t(regmatches(txt, gregexpr("(?<=')[0-9.]+(?=')",txt,perl=TRUE))[[1]]))
df

                  X1               X2
1 12.839006423950195 77.6580810546875
```

Comment: `regmatches(txt, gregexpr("(?<=')[0-9.]+(?=')",txt,perl=TRUE))` is what you are looking for to extract regex matches in base R

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`.  We use regex lookarounds to match one or more numbers with decimals (`[0-9.]+`) which is within the single quotes (`(?<=')` and `(?=')`).

```
library(stringr)
lst <- lapply(str_extract_all(txt, "(?<=')[0-9.]+(?=')") , as.numeric)
```

If we have the same length for list elements

```
df1 <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst), paste0('V', 1:2))
```

would get 2 column 'data.frame'

#### data

```
txt <- ":location: - '12.839006423950195' - '77.6580810546875' :last_location_update: 2015-08-10 16:41:46.817000000 Z"
```